# IndexOutOfBoundsException: in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, arrays, object

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at com.ppl.adapter.FoodRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FoodRecyclerViewAdapter.java:99)
at com.ppl.adapter.FoodRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FoodRecyclerViewAdapter.java:24)
```

What wrongs? Plz Explain me. Food have data. FoodCategory also have data.

In Food Object;

```
private Integer id;
private String foodName;
// etc.
private List<FoodSize> foodSizes = new ArrayList<FoodSize>();
```

In FoodSize Object;

```
private Integer price;
// etc

public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
```

In FoodRecyclerViewAdapter;

```
List<Food> contents;    

public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position);
    if (contents.get(position).getFoodSizes().get(0).getPrice() != null) {
                        holder.foodPrice.setText(contents.get(position).getFoodSizes().get(0).getPrice().toString());
                    }
```

Here;

```
[
 {
        "id": 1,
        "food_name": "Chicken",
            "food_category": { },
            "food_sizes": [
              {
                "id": 84,
                "size": "Normal",
                "food_id": 1,
                "price": 1100,
              }
            ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Probably you have nothing in `contents`. Are you sure you have parsed your `JSON` successfully ?

Comment: check whether contents array have value or not?

Comment: Which ones are lines 99 and 24 and by the way, where are you initializing `contents` or `foodSizes`? Please add more code. And what do you mean by "Here" and then you post JSON? Show the code where you parse JSON.

Comment: in contents. Here is api. :D I use Retrofit

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        FoodSize mfoodSize = (FoodSize)foodSizes.get(position);

        holder.foodPrice.setText(mfoodSize.getPrice().toString());

}
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: Why are you casting it to `FoodSize` when your list is already of type `FoodSize` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in `getCount()` method :

write like bellow :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (contents != null) return contents.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
if (contents.get(position).getFoodSizes().size() > 0) {
                    holder.foodPrice.setText(contents.get(position).getFoodSizes().get(0).getPrice().toString());
                } else {
                    Log.i("Price 0", " 0");
                }
```